# Heroku - Not Found

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, heroku

(I changed some of the code to mask specific account info, I'm a beginner, not sure it's important but just changed stuff anyways)

Hi, I'm a beginner going through a tutorial on deploying a react + flask app.

I've successfully deployed my app on Heroku but when I go to view it on Heroku I get:

**Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

Here is app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
#from flask_cors import CORS #comment this on deployment
from api.HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='frontend/build')
#CORS(app) #comment this on deployment
api = Api(app)

@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

api.add_resource(HelloApiHandler, '/flask/hello')
```

Here is my app.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [getMessage, setGetMessage] = useState({})

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('https://example.herokuapp.com/flask/hello').then(response => {
      console.log("Success", response)
      setGetMessage(response)
    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>React + Flask Tutorial</p>
    <div>{getMessage.status === 200 ?
      <h3>{getMessage.data.message}</h3>
      :
      <h3>LOADING</h3>}</div> 
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my HelloApiHandler.py

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

class HelloApiHandler(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {
            'resultStatus': 'SUCCESS',
            'message': "Hello Api Handler"
                }

    def post(self):
        print(self)
        parser=reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('type', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('message', type=str)

        args = parser.parse_args()

        print(args)
        # note, the post req from frontend needs to match the strings here (e.g. 'type' and 'message')

        request_type = args['type']
        request_json = args['message']

        #ret_status, ret_msg = ReturnData(request_type, request_json)
        # currently just returning the req straight
        ret_status = request_type
        ret_msg = request_json


        if ret_msg:
            message = "Your Message Requested: {}".format(ret_msg)
        else:
            message = "No msg"


        final_ret = {'status': 'Success', 'message': message}

        return final_ret
```

here is the Heroku log message every time I go to my site:

```
2021-05-25T03:12:30.581589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=example.herokuapp.com request_id=9b7ce9-84c-17a809-78ad83d2e34 fwd="170.200.2.30" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `https://example.herokuapp.com/flask/hello` this is a correct url?

Comment: yeah, because it works locally

Comment: in fact that url works just fine on the deployed app.  It's just the root that doesn't work for some reason.